# Spark: How to union a List<RDD> to RDD

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I'm pretty new to spark and scala language and would like to union all RDDs in a List as below(`List<RDD> to RDD`) :

```
 val data = for (item <- paths) yield {
        val ad_data_path = item._1
        val ad_data = SparkCommon.sc.textFile(ad_data_path).map {
            line => {
                val ad_data = new AdData(line)
                (ad_data.ad_id, ad_data)
            }
        }.distinct()
    }
 val ret = SparkCommon.sc.parallelize(data).reduce(_ ++ _)
```

I run the code in IntelliJ while always get an error as:

```
ava.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.<init>(RDD.scala:125)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.<init>(UnionRDD.scala:59)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.union(RDD.scala:438)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$plus$plus(RDD.scala:444)
at data.GenerateData$$anonfun$load_data$1.apply(GenerateData.scala:99)
at data.GenerateData$$anonfun$load_data$1.apply(GenerateData.scala:99)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$reduceLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:177)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$$anonfun$reduceLeft$1.apply(TraversableOnce.scala:172)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceLeft(TraversableOnce.scala:172)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.reduceLeft(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$18.apply(RDD.scala:847)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$18.apply(RDD.scala:845)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$26.apply(SparkContext.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$26.apply(SparkContext.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:62)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:54)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:177)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Anyone has any idea about the error? Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This might be the cause,

```
val listA = 1 to 10
for(i <- listA; if i%2 == 0)yield {i}
```

will return Vector(2,4,6,8,10), whereas

```
for(i <- listA; if i%2 == 0)yield {val c = i}
```

will return Vector ((),(),(),(),())

That is exactly what is happening in your case. You are initializing **ad_data** but not returning it back to yield.

***As far as your question is concerned ,i.e List[RDD] to RDD***

here is the solution:

```
val listA = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
val listB = sc.parallelize(10 to 1 by -1)
```

creating **list of 2 RDDS**

```
val listC = List(listA,listB)
```

convert **List[RDD] to RDD**

```
val listD = listC.reduce(_ union _)
```

Hope, this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is solved with your solution.

Comment: @juffun , can u accept the answer , if solution worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Another simple method to convert from List of RDD's to RDD.
SparkContext has two overloaded union methods, one accepts two RDDs and other accepts List of RDDs

union(first, rest)
union(rdds: Seq[RDD[T]]))